# Unable to setRotation to PhysicsBody::createBox in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm able to rotate the sprite 90-degree angle but unable to change the angle of the physics body. My purpose is to connect multiple sprites with createBlock() to make a breakable tower object. I want to add setRotation() to PhysicsBody::createBox but error showed up and was unable to implement what I want to do. I googled for some solutions but wasn't able to find a helpful solution to my problem. I would love to hear some tips or examples from you!

Here is the function to create a Block sprite. Added 90 so that the sprite will be rotated to 90 degrees.

```
createBlock(BlockType::Block1, Point(586, 150), 90);
```

↓

```
void GameLayer::createBlock(BlockType type, Point position, float angle)
{
    std::string fileName;

    switch (type)
    {
        case BlockType::Block1:
            fileName = "block1.png";
            break;

        case BlockType::Block2:
            fileName = "block2.png";
            break;

        case BlockType::Roof:
            fileName = "roof.png";
            break;

        default:
            fileName = "stone.png";
            break;
    }

    auto block = Sprite::create(fileName.c_str());
    block->setPosition(position);
    block->setRotation(angle);
    block->setTag(T_Block);

    PhysicsBody* body;

    switch (type)
    {
        case BlockType::Block1:
        case BlockType::Block2:
        {

            body = PhysicsBody::createBox(block->getContentSize(), PhysicsMaterial(0.5, 0.5, 0.3));
            body->setDynamic(true);
            body->setContactTestBitmask(0x01);
            break;
        }

        case BlockType::Roof:
        {
            Point points[3] = {Point(-50, -25), Point(0, 25), Point(50, -25)};
            body = PhysicsBody::createPolygon(points, 3, PhysicsMaterial(0.5, 0.5, 0.3));
            body->setDynamic(true);
            body->setContactTestBitmask(0x01);
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            body = PhysicsBody::createBox(block->getContentSize(), PhysicsMaterial(0.5, 0.5, 0.3));
            body->setDynamic(false);
            break;
        }
    }

    block->setPhysicsBody(body);


    addChild(block, Z_Block);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate not only the sprite but also physics, we must call `setRotation(angle)` after calling `block->setPhysicsBody(body)`.

So, please fix code like below...

1st: `block->setPhysicsBody(body);`

next: `block->setRotation(angle);`

last: `addChild(block, Z_Block);`

I know your code and have experienced same problem before! I have this text book, too.(^ ^)